# Excel VBA: Copying Cell Contents

Tags: vba, excel, copy, paste

I have an excel program that runs a test plan for product configurations. In this program, the user clicks the "test plan" button which will then run the configuration on each product. When this happens, information from other sheets is gathered to find out the costs and totals. I have been able to gather the total costs in each column, multiply by the rates, and add each of the totals together to get the total labor costs, total material costs, total labor MTO costs, and total material MTO costs. I would much like to store these totals in another sheet, called "Totals", so I can easily monitor and manipulate them later.

However, when I try to store these values in the cells I want it will only return the most recent sheets values. (It is important to note that when the program is ran by clicking the button, old sheets with old data are deleted and replaced by newer ones. This means I cannot place any formulas within the sheets, it has to be VBA code and I do not know how many sheets will be made.) I have tried many different approaches, two of which I'll post.

```
    For i = 1 To 10
        wsTotals.Cells(1, i).Value = laborTotal
        wsTotals.Cells(2, i).Value = laborMTOTotal
    Next i
```

Here I tried to store the values I calculated into cells on the Totals sheet. But when it is ran, only the 2 most recent values are copied. (laborTotal in row 1, A through J and laborMTOTotal in row 2, A through J). However, instead of just these two values, there should be 8 for my testing since I have 4 sheets.

I have also tried:

```
    wsNewSheet.Range("AN1:AO1").Copy 'I stored the totals out of the way of vision to try to copy them later
    wsTotals.Select
    wsTotals.Range("A1:J2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

This returned a similar result. Any help is much appreciated and I can give more information if necessary.

EDIT: I should also add that when the program is ran a new sheet is created for each smart number entered by the user on the "Test Plan" sheet. In my code, I have simply been looping through each sheet to perform the appropriate task. My problem here is that it isn't grabbing each total (or it's simply replacing the totals at the end by the most previous ones). Each new sheet is stored in "wsNewSheet".

Okay, let me try this one more time. Here is my code:

```
Function Test_MLFB(sMLFB, sPattern) As Boolean
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^" & Replace(sPattern, "…", "...") & "$"
re.IgnoreCase = False
Test_MLFB = re.Test(sMLFB)
End Function

Function Test_Option_Code(sCode, sPattern) As Boolean
Set re = New RegExp
bInvert = False
If Left(sPattern, 1) = "!" Then
    sPattern = Right(sPattern, Len(sPattern) - 1)
    bInvert = True
End If
re.Pattern = "^.*" & sPattern & ".*$"
If bInvert Then Test_Option_Code = Not (re.Test(sCode)) Else Test_Option_Code = re.Test(sCode)
End Function

Function Test_MLFB_OPTS(sConfiguration, sMLFBm, sOpt1m, sOpt2m, sOpt3m, sOpt4m, sOpt5m) As Boolean
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = f_Lookahead(sOpt5m) & f_Lookahead(sOpt4m) & f_Lookahead(sOpt3m) & f_Lookahead(sOpt2m) & f_Lookahead(sOpt1m) & Replace(sMLFBm, "…", "...")
Test_MLFB_OPTS = re.Test(sConfiguration)
End Function

Function f_Lookahead(sOpt_mask) As String
    If sOpt_mask = "" Then
        f_Lookahead = ""
    ElseIf Left(sOpt_mask, 1) = "!" Then 'negative lookahead assertion
        f_Lookahead = "(?!.*" & Right(sOpt_mask, Len(sOpt_mask) - 1) & ")"
    Else 'positive lookahead assertion
        f_Lookahead = "(?=.*" & sOpt_mask & ")"
    End If
End Function

Function Run_Test()
Remove_Old_Instance_BoMs
Run_Test_Case

End Function

Function Remove_Old_Instance_BoMs()

iSheetCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
For Each aSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If Not (aSheet.Name = "Test Plan" Or aSheet.Name = "SBoM" Or aSheet.Name = "Transformer SN" Or aSheet.Name = "Tables" Or aSheet.Name = "Phase" _
    Or aSheet.Name = "bomcost.csv" Or aSheet.Name = "bomtrafocost.csv" Or aSheet.Name = "bomhourlyrate.csv" Or aSheet.Name = "base" _
    Or aSheet.Name = "digit 9" Or aSheet.Name = "digit 14" Or aSheet.Name = "digit 15" Or aSheet.Name = "options" Or aSheet.Name = "rates" _
    Or aSheet.Name = "opt short desc" Or aSheet.Name = "Totals" Or aSheet.Name = "bomcostINFO" Or aSheet.Name = "bomcost" Or aSheet.Name = "trans") Then
        'MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
        aSheet.Delete
    End If
Next
End Function

Function Run_Test_Case()
Dim totals As Worksheet
Dim bApplies As Boolean
Dim buildRate As Long
Dim sysBuildRate As Long
Dim testRate As Long
Dim engRate As Long
'the following are columns of the SBOM
iType = 5
iPosNum = 6 'f
iQtyNum = 7
iMatlNum = 8
iMatlDesc = 9
imlfbmask = 11
iOpt1Mask = 12
iOpt2Mask = 13
iOpt3Mask = 14
iOpt4Mask = 15
iOpt5Mask = 16
inMTOmPartDesc = 20
inMTOmCost = 21
iTotalMatCost = 22
inMTOmDTKCost = 23
iTotalLabCost = 24
inMTOmHAWACost = 25
inMTOmCurrency = 26
inMTOmBuildHrs = 27
inMTOmSysBuildHrs = 28
inMTOmTestHrs = 29
inMTOmEngHrs = 30
inMTOmIndex = 31
iMTOmPartDesc = 32
iMTOmCost = 33
iMTOmTotalMatCost = 34
iMTOmDTKCost = 35
iMTOmTotalLabCost = 36
iMTOmHAWACost = 37
iMTOmCurrency = 38
iMTOmBuildHrs = 39
iMTOmSysBuildHrs = 40
iMTOmTestHrs = 41
iMTOmEngHrs = 42

For iRow = 2 To 152 'Rows of Test Plan
    Set curTestCase = Worksheets("Test Plan").Cells(iRow, 1)
    Set curMLFBCell = Worksheets("Test Plan").Cells(iRow, 2)
    Set curoptlistcell = Worksheets("Test Plan").Cells(iRow, 3)
    Set wsSBoM = Worksheets("SBoM")
    Set wsTotals = Worksheets("Totals")
    If Not (IsEmpty(curMLFBCell)) And Not (IsEmpty(curoptlistcell)) Then
        Set wsNewSheet = Worksheets.Add
        wsNewSheet.Name = curTestCase.Value
        Worksheets("Test Plan").Rows(iRow).Copy
        wsNewSheet.Rows("1:1").Select
        wsNewSheet.Paste

        iNewSheetRow = 2
        For iSBoMRow = 4 To 1271
            bApplies = False
            If Not IsEmpty(wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, imlfbmask)) Then
                bApplies = Test_MLFB_OPTS(curMLFBCell.Value & curoptlistcell.Value, wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, imlfbmask).Value, wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, _
                iOpt1Mask).Value, wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iOpt2Mask).Value, wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iOpt3Mask).Value, wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, _
                iOpt4Mask).Value, wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iOpt5Mask).Value)
            End If

            If bApplies Then
                iNewSheetRow = iNewSheetRow + 1
                wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 1).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iPosNum).Value
                wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 2).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iQtyNum).Value
                wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 3).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iMatlNum).Value
                wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 4).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iMatlDesc).Value
                wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 5).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iType).Value
                If wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iType).Value = 1 Then
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 6).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, inMTOmPartDesc).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 7).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, inMTOmCost).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 8).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iTotalMatCost).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 9).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, inMTOmDTKCost).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 10).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iTotalLabCost).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 11).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, inMTOmHAWACost).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 12).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, inMTOmCurrency).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 13).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, inMTOmBuildHrs).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 14).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, inMTOmSysBuildHrs).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 15).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iMTOmTestHrs).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 16).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iMTOmEngHrs).Value

                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 18).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, inMTOmIndex).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 19).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iMTOmPartDesc).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 21).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iMTOmCost).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 22).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iMTOmTotalMatCost).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 23).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iMTOmDTKCost).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 24).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iMTOmTotalLabCost).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 25).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iMTOmHAWACost).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 26).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iMTOmCurrency).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 27).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iMTOmBuildHrs).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 28).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iMTOmSysBuildHrs).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 29).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iMTOmTestHrs).Value
                    wsNewSheet.Cells(iNewSheetRow, 30).Value = wsSBoM.Cells(iSBoMRow, iMTOmEngHrs).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next iSBoMRow

        wsNewSheet.Range("G1:AD1").Formula = "=SUM(G2:G152)"
        wsNewSheet.Range("G1:AD1").NumberFormat = "0.00"
        buildRate = (wsNewSheet.Cells(1, 13).Value * 123.35)
        MTOBuildRate = (wsNewSheet.Cells(1, 27).Value * 123.35)
        sysBuildRate = (wsNewSheet.Cells(1, 14).Value * 123.35)
        MTOSysBuildRate = (wsNewSheet.Cells(1, 28).Value * 123.35)
        testRate = (wsNewSheet.Cells(1, 15).Value * 126.22)
        MTOTestRate = (wsNewSheet.Cells(1, 29).Value * 126.22)
        engRate = (wsNewSheet.Cells(1, 16).Value * 97.14)
        MTOEngRate = (wsNewSheet.Cells(1, 30).Value * 97.14)

        laborBuild = (wsNewSheet.Cells(1, 10).Value + buildRate)
        laborSysBuild = (wsNewSheet.Cells(1, 10).Value + sysBuildRate)
        laborTestBuild = (wsNewSheet.Cells(1, 10).Value + testRate)
        laborEngBuild = (wsNewSheet.Cells(1, 10).Value + engRate)
        laborMTOBuild = (wsNewSheet.Cells(1, 10).Value + MTOBuildRate)
        laborMTOSysBuild = (wsNewSheet.Cells(1, 10).Value + MTOSysBuildRate)
        laborMTOTestBuild = (wsNewSheet.Cells(1, 10).Value + MTOTestRate)
        laborMTOEngBuild = (wsNewSheet.Cells(1, 10).Value + MTOEngRate)

        laborTotal = (laborBuild + laborSysBuild + laborTestBuild + laborEngBuild)
        laborMTOTotal = (laborMTOBuild + laborMTOSysBuild + laborMTOTestBuild + laborMTOEngBuild)

    End If
Next iRow
End Function
```

Comment: You're going to need to show more of your code. As currently written, it's not possible to determine what you're doing wrong.  Also, you may want to include some more detail about the address of your named ranges ("TotalCells" and "LaborTotals").  But mostly, I want to see the code that precedes the `For i = 1 to 10` loop.

Comment: No problem. I have put up more information and I'm not trying to make this too long. "TotalCells" and "LaborTotals" have been replaced with their ranges.

Comment: You did not include enough of your code.  As it is currently written, your loop is running 10 times. That is probably what you expect. but it is only running against a single worksheet.  I would guess that all of the preceding information which you added, **and** a correct assignment to the variable `wsNewSheet` should also go inside of a loop, defnining which sheet is `wsNewSheet`, so the calculations would perform on each sheet.

Comment: That is correct. I use a loop to create each sheet for each number entered by the user with the corresponding information and then do the calculations. I will include the rest of my code just prepare for the length.

Comment: No no no no no. You need to please put ALL of your code AS IT APPEARS in your subroutine. Don't put separate chunks of it out of order -- at least not if you expect anyone to assist...

Comment: Within your loop you need to A) Create the `wsNewSheet`, B) perform the calculations as required for *that* worksheet, and C) write the values out to that worksheet.  All of that needs to happen in the same loop.  If you start pulling things outside of that loop, then they will only ever refer to the most-recent `wsNewSheet`.

Comment: All of that is in my loop. So far, nothing has been outside of it.

Comment: There is nothing in your current code that is doing `wsTotals.Cells(1, i).Value = laborTotal` (e.g., the interior of the `For i = 1 to 10` loop that you originally cite as problematic... What is your **actual problem**? At this point, you're about to lose me because it seems you do not know basic debugging techniques...

Comment: Why would I leave it in there if it does not work? It was at the end right below the calculations as I originally stated. Don't worry I will work the problem out myself. I love this site and all of the help I get from it, but you guys are so picky about everything it just becomes a hassle to post anything. Thanks for your time and enjoy your day.

Comment: Because without showing the code you're *actually using*, it's impossible to determine what the problem is or might be.  We have now 10 comments trying to clarify what you're actually asking -- I'm very good at VBA, but I'm pretty lousy at mind-reading so I'm sorry if this seems like a "hassle" to you, but you're the one asking for help, and it's really not possible to help unless we can see the code in question, not just snippets out of context.

Comment: The reason I only put "snippets out of context" is because in my last few posts I was told not to code dump and now I'm told to not use snippets.

Comment: You need to provide the minimum amount of code that would be required for someone else to replicate the problem you're having... this includes variable declarations, assignment statements, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I try to store these values in the cells I want it will only return the most recent sheets values.

Because you only have *one* (i.e., the "most recent") value in any of your variables.  So a loop like this takes that *one* most recent value and puts it in 10 different cells:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    wsTotals.Cells(1, i).Value = laborTotal
    wsTotals.Cells(2, i).Value = laborMTOTotal
Next i
```

This code is doing exactly what you have told it to do. This may differ from what you *want* it to do.  So, what do you actually *want* it to do? This is a `1 to 10` loop, so the relationship between the new sheets (152 of them) you create at run-time and this loop is not immediately apparent.

So, when `i` = 1, `laborTotal` will be computed from the data on `wsNewSheet`.

**When `i` = 2, how should this value be computed???**

**UPDATE FROM COMMENTS**

I don't understand why you have `For i = 1 to 10...` which would be a nested loop within your `iRow` loop. As you have explained it, I think that is not necessary.

I think this should put the value of `laborTotal` in row 1 of the `Totals` sheet, and the value of `laborMTOTotal` in row 2 of `Totals` sheet.

```
    ...
    laborMTOTestBuild = (wsNewSheet.Cells(1, 10).Value + MTOTestRate)
    laborMTOEngBuild = (wsNewSheet.Cells(1, 10).Value + MTOEngRate)

    laborTotal = (laborBuild + laborSysBuild + laborTestBuild + laborEngBuild)
    laborMTOTotal = (laborMTOBuild + laborMTOSysBuild + laborMTOTestBuild + laborMTOEngBuild)

    '## ADD THESE LINES, or modify as needed:
    wsTotals.Cells(1, iRow).Value = laborTotal
    wsTotals.Cells(2, iRow).Value = laborMTOTotal

End If
```

Comment: Okay, so, in my head of mine this how I believe it should be going. The "run test" button is click; old sheets are deleted. The program runs through the first loop, creates the sheet, puts all of the information together, performs calculations, and then I believe it should store the totals in "laborTotal" and "laborMTOTotal" then put these values in the Totals sheet. Then it will perform the next loop with the second new sheet, put it all together, perform calculations, and store new values in the total variables and then, again store this information in the Totals sheet.

Comment: It should continue this process until there are no more configurations on the "Test Plan" sheet. When i = 2, the program should be on cell B2 storing the information held by laborMTOTotal on the second time around the loop.

Comment: See update. I think the confusing part is why you initially have that inside a `For i = 1 to 10` loop, nested in your `iRow` iteration.  If you get rid of the nested loop and just assign value to the `wsTotals`, will that fix it?

Comment: Thank you. That worked great. Apologies for the irritation, but everytime I post something on Stack Overflow there is always something I do wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. It can be tricky at first but you will get the hang of it :)  there is a fine line between "code dump" and "not enough code"!  If this has solved the problem, do mark the answer as "Accepted".